# При попытке сборки проекта появляется ошибка Could not find android.arch.persistece.room:compiler:1.0.0

Tags: android, android-room, android-gradle, room

При попытке сборки проекта появляется следующая ошибка. Как от нее избавиться?

```
Could not find android.arch.persistece.room:compiler:1.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/persistece /room/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/persistece/room/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.jar
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/persistece/room/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/persistece/room/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341513/android-roomdatabase-could-not-resolve-android-arch-persistence-roomcompiler

Comment: @ValeraKvip я сделал все в точности как описано в этом вопросе но это не сработало. В моем build.gradle(project) файле есть и google и jcenter. В настройках gradle offline work не активирован.

Comment: Не припомню сложности в подключении Room, просто прописал в app.gradle  :                   
    def room_version = '2.2.3'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

Comment: @JackFromBB как раз только что именно так и подключил. До этого подключал следующим образом: compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0" и annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0" После изменения все заработало. Вопрос решен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарии к моему вопросу господин JackFromBB предложил правильный вариант
Для подключения Room я использовал следующие зависимости

```
dependencies {
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    ...
}
```

В документации же для подключения Room описаны следующие зависимости

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.2.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```